# Simple textbox populating based on combobox

Tags: c#

I'd like to populate a textbox from a combobox without using a database. For example i'm using GDP per country, and when the country is selected from the dropdown it populates the textbox with that countries GDP annually. Which will be entered as a string since there's only 3 countries in the dropdown.

Everywhere i look it imports a database or excel sheet and that's not what I'd like to do. Very simple here and it's difficult to find the simplicity.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (btnCountry.Text)
        {
            case "United States":
                MessageBox.Show("You have selected the United States");
                btnAnually.Clear();
                btnAnually.("$1,000,000");

                break;
            case "Iran":
                MessageBox.Show("You have selected Iran");
                btnAnually.Clear();
                btnAnually.Equals("$2,000,000");


                break;
            case "Libya":
                MessageBox.Show("You have selected Libya");
                btnAnually.Clear();
                btnAnually.Equals("3,000,000");

                break;
        }

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here `combobox1_selectedIndexChanged `? Is this a field, property, etc? `textbox2_TextChanged = "$1,000,000";` what are you expecting this to do? You should handle the [SelectedIndexChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) event of the `combobox` and then assign the `Text` property of the textbox...

Comment: Please only add relevant tags. I've removed [`vba`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vba/info) and [`visual-studio`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/visual-studio/info) for you.

Comment: I've made it clearer, is there a function to add items to show in a textbox? if i were adding it to another dropdown it would be .Items.add()

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to do something when your combobox changes, you'll want to handle that event, not the textbox changed.
2. You should set your textbox's text.
3. You should check on the combox1's selectedIndex.

Something like this:

```
 private void combobox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
  if(combobox1.SelectedIndex == 0){
         textbox2.Text = "$1,000,000";
  }
 }
```

Comment: `combobox1_selectedIndexChanged` is probably an event handler as well (and that -1 wasn't me).

Comment: Ok, checking textbox1_textchanged doesn't make mush sense either. Updated the answer

Comment: I think my code made it more confusing. based on combobox selection, i'd like to populate the textbox so selecting Product 1 in the dropdown would automagically put $5 in the text box below it

Comment: @Postman507 well then, *reading the code* in this answer should get you there. You want to assign `theTextBox.Text = "the string value you want"`.